# How to determine if a collection of edge-lengths corresponds to the edges of a Complete Graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

In the **Euclidean Plane** and where **all edges are straight lines**:

Given a collection of a edge-lengths ***L***, how can I determine if there exists a selection of vertices such that the elements of ***L*** correspond exactly to the distances between each unique pairing of vertices?

---

For instance, when ***L***=[3, 4, 5] a selection of vertices (0, 0), (0, 3), and (4, 0) satisfies these properties.

However, when ***L***=[3, 4, 8] there is no collection of vertices who's complete graph consists exactly of three edges with lengths 3, 4, and 8; since any complete graph *(in the Euclidean Plane)* having three edges is a triangle, and a triangle's longest edge must be less than the sum of the other two.

---

- What if the vertices must have **rational** coordinates?
- What if the vertices must have **integer** coordinates?
- Does the collinearity *(or lack thereof)* of vertices matter?

---

**UPDATE:**

I read that any complete graph of **n** vertices is composed of exactly **$ {n\choose 3} $** triangles. So, I guess I can rule out any ***L*** with an edge-length longer than or equal to the sum of the next two shorter edge-lengths?

Comment: I don't have the time right now to go looking, but the basic question here has been asked several times, if not the variations with rational/integer coordinates.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I'm unsure about my terminology. What keywords should I be looking for?

Comment: Start from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533475, which is definitely the wrong variant of this question but has links to many more, and that should give you some keywords

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partial answer found here: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062113](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062113/when-can-a-weighted-graph-be-embedded-in-a-metric-space)

---

Naturally, the size of ***L*** will always be a triangle number. 
The number of vertices (***n***) in a complete graph with ***L*.size** edges is:
$$ 
n=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8L {\scriptsize\text{.size}}}}{2} 
$$

***L*** can complete a graph of ***n*** vertices when there is an assignment of edges to vertices such that:

1. No two edges connect the same pair of vertices.
2. The edges of each 3-vertex cycle obey the triangle inequality.

---

I don't know the best way to determine if such an assignment exits. 
You can brute force every combination until finding one that works, but I'm sure there's a better way. 
It may warrant a post of its own.